# Prevent QML MouseArea from taking focus when pressed

Tags: qml, sailfish-os

In my application, I have a `TextArea`, and under it a toolbar with `Button` items. Whenever a `Button` gets pressed, the `TextArea` loses focus, and hides the virtual keyboard (which is right). But what if I want the `TextArea` to keep its focus, even if a `Button` has been pressed?

In SailfishOS, `Button` is just a `MouseArea`, not a QML `Button`. This means there is no property `Button.activeFocusOnPress` that I could set to `false`. Is there a way to replicate this behaviour for the `MouseArea`?

Here's some code:

```
    TextArea {
      id: editor
      width: parent.width
      height: 200
      anchors.top: pageHeader.bottom
      anchors.bottom: toolbar.top
    }

    ListModel {
      id: textNavButtons
      ListElement {buttonText: "left"}
      ListElement {buttonText: "right"}
      ListElement {buttonText: "tab"}
      ListElement {buttonText: "home"}
      ListElement {buttonText: "end"}
    }

    Row {
      id: toolbar
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
      width: parent.width
      height: 80

      Repeater {
        id: toolbarRepeater
        model: textNavButtons
        property int modelCount: model.count

        delegate: Button {
          text: buttonText
          width: parent.width / toolbarRepeater.modelCount
          onClicked: {
            console.log("I was clicked: " + text);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

EDIT: My goal is to use these buttons to insert tabs into the text, or to navigate with Home, End, Left, Right etc. I'm not sure if using these buttons will achieve the goal, but I had no other idea. I will have to simulate the keypress too.

Comment: For Button : `onFocusChanged : if(true == focus) { editor.focus = true }`

Comment: @AmitTomar why not an answer? And you can just do `if (focus) {` this is because `focus == true` will evaluate to a `bool`, which `focus` already is.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution suggested by @AmitTomar doesn't work very well. It does transfer the focus to the TextArea, but the virtual keyboard hides itself and stays hidden.

Comment: @CamilB Probably you should try looking for ways to invoke the virtual keyboard manually using some sailfish API then. Is there a text element provided by them for similar purposes in their API?

Comment: @AmitTomar `Maliit` is the keyboard framework. It looks like it can be invoked, but I can't find any docs. also, there's the `com.jolla.keyboard` package in QML which is used by Maliit, but I'm yet to figure out how to use it, or even what it contains.

Comment: @CamilB See if this could be of some help : https://gitorious.org/maliit/maliit-framework/source/f562ad91ee14680aaafc6401428ef259a9e61598:examples/apps/qml/enterKeyCustomization.qml I don't have the setup, so can't really test it.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use

```
delegate: Button {
      text: buttonText
      width: parent.width / toolbarRepeater.modelCount
      focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
      onClicked: {
        console.log("I was clicked: " + text);
      }
    }
```